# Why is YAML.safe_load failing on a YAML alias?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml, react-on-rails

I've a locale file in my Rails application that works fine with Rails, but when I tried to use it with react_on_rails rake task (`rake react_on_rails:locale`) I'm getting this error:

```
Psych::BadAlias: Unknown alias: item_attributes
```

I found that the rake task is basically calling `YAML.safe_load`, so I prepared the simplest example without Rails and the error is still there. Here's the sample Ruby script:

```
require 'yaml'

YAML.safe_load(File.open('test.yml'))
```

And here's the test.yml file (shorter version of the actual locale file):

```
pl:
  language: Polski
  dictionary_name: simple
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      line_item: &item_attributes
        variant: Produkt
        quantity: Ilosc
        price: Cena Netto
        total_price: Wartosc Netto
        vat_rate: VAT
        total_vat_amount: Kwota VAT
        total_gross_price: Wartosc Brutto
      order_item:
        <<: *item_attributes
```

I'm still getting the error:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:402:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Alias': Unknown alias: item_attributes (Psych::BadAlias)
```

Any ideas why this works fine with Rails but fails here? Any other way to avoid duplication in the YAML file and make it work for both Rails and `YAML.safe_load`?

Comment: I would guess that `<<` is not supported with `YAML.safe_load`. you could try if `<<: {foo: bar}` works. If not, this is not an alias problem.

Comment: @flyx yes, it does work, so that's not it

Comment: Strange indeed. There's no YAML syntax error here, maybe there are two different YAML parsers involved?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I found an answer in the Psych documentation, at https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/psych/rdoc/Psych.html.

> Aliases can be explicitly allowed by changing the aliases parameter. For example:

```
x = []
x << x
yaml = Psych.dump x
Psych.safe_load yaml               # => raises an exception
Psych.safe_load yaml, [], [], true # => loads the aliases
```

Whether to allow aliases or not is a boolean passed to `safe_load` as the fourth argument.

Comment: in 2.6 and later versions, you can use `Psych.safe_load yaml, aliases: true # => loads the aliases`
https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/psych/rdoc/Psych.html